# Pandas efficient way to add values to a column if the element exists in another pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I have two pandas dataframe(df1 and df2). df1 contains a column of strings who are to be matched with substrings from a column in df2 and saved to a seperate column. I can do this with apply but the computation is really slow. Is it possible to vectorize it? Or any other way to improve efficiency? Both the columns are large in size.

Thanks

```
def get_city(location, city_list):
    if(isinstance(location, str)):
        suspects_list = []
        location=location.lower()
        for city in city_list:
            if(city in location):
                suspects_list.append(city)
        if(suspects_list):
            return max(suspects_list, key=len)
        else:
            return np.nan
    else:
        return np.nan

df['city'] = df['location'].apply(
lambda element: get_city(element, world_cities_list))
```

Location column contains strings that are not cleaned which may or may not contain name of city as substring. We need to extract the cities as store in a column named city. Cities are distributed worldwide so the whole dataset for cities is 40,000+. The length of location column is 150,000+.

Comment: Could you share example data and code that you have tried so far?

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler added the code. Sorry for not adding it earlier. Please check.

Comment: proper idents in code would be also helpful

Comment: @EvgenyPogrebnyak Sorry for not noticing it.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://tomaugspurger.github.io/modern-4-performance.html

Answer (score 0):

I wish there was some hint of initial data, but here is a small speedup.

First you need to take care of outer check for str type outside this function in a separate call, eg slice your orginal dataframe to valid rows only.

Then you can do the following:

```
import numpy as np

def get_city(location, cities):
    filter1 = lambda x: location.lower() in x
    suspects = list(filter(filter1, cities))
    if suspects:
        return max(suspects, key=len)
    else:
        return np.nan

cities = ['moscow', 'moscow, russia', 'kiev']     
assert get_city('MOSCOW', cities) == 'moscow, russia'
```

Hope it is expected behaviour.